# Quais são as ferramentas de acessibilidade para web?

Tags: aplicação-web, acessibilidade

Olá, eu estou com problemas para encontrar algumas ferramentas ou tutoriais que me permitam implementar recursos de acessibilidade no meu projeto da faculdade.

Eu gostaria de saber quais são as formas de se implementar recursos de acessibilidade em um sistema `web` e se existem `frameworks` que possam fazer esse trabalho.

Eu estou usando `Web Forms` e `Master Page` no `visual Studio`, a programação do sistema é em `C#`. Eu gostaria que as ferramentas apresentadas possam ajudar também a trabalhar com essa tecnologia sem conflitos.

Só pra complementar, recursos de acessibilidade são aqueles que permitam deficientes utilizarem o sistema, muita gente confunde acessibilidade com responsividade que é o que permite o sistema ser acessado por vários dispositivos com tamanhos de telas diferentes.

Um exemplo de acessibilidade seria modificar as cores para portadores de Daltonismo poderem diferenciar os elementos da página. Eu gostaria que o meu sistema pudesse ser acessível para alguns portadores de deficiências visuais.

Os recursos de Acessibilidade que eu procuro são os de aumento de fontes e o recurso que permita modificar o estilo de cores da página. Pois acredito que somente esses dois já ajudem bastante os usuários.

Comment: Olá sua pergunta parece ser baseada em opiniões , e perguntas baseadas em opiniões são fora do escopo do site entende ?  tente reformular para algo como  "Quais são as ferramentas de acessibilidade para web ? " mencione sua dúvida relacionando os conceitos em envolvidos  .etc ( não conheço quase nada sobre o assunto então  não vou poder te sugerir muita coisa ).

Comment: Ok eu já reformatei a pergunta, o que eu percebi é que é muito difícil encontrar alguma coisa que permita implementar acessibilidade em sistemas web.

Comment: "me indicar algum tutorial ou um framework" poderia ser trocado por exemplo "quais são as formas de implementar os recursos de acessibilidade no desenvolvimento do meu site ? ."(apenas um exemplo saca? ) e um tema interessante , logo os especialistas no assunto irão te dizer algo rs , só que seu enunciado no momento ainda está no formato "Alguém pode me dar uma sugestão  ? " entendeu ?  isso se encaixa em perguntas baseadas em opiniões ^^.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Antônio, se você especificar as tecnologias que pretende usar, ficará mais fácil de alguém de te ajudar.

Comment: Pronto amigo, já especifiquei as tecnologias que estou usando, espero que isso ajude. Obrigado pela dica

Comment: Eu discordo que a sua pergunta seja baseada em opiniões. Ainda assim, do jeito que ela está agora ela me parece ampla demais. Acessibilidade é um assunto vasto, e métodos ou ferramentas dependerão do tipo de dificuldade que os usuários do seu sistema terão. Por exemplo, o daltonismo é um tipo específico de dificuldade visual, mas há outros (variando até a cegueira completa). Há também dificuldades motoras, cognitivas, auditivas, e por ai vai.

Comment: Assim, talvez fosse mais interessante você editar a pergunta para incluir detalhes dos usuários do seu sistema e focar em algum exemplo concreto de interface/interação que você esteja trabalhando. Lembrando: vc pode abrir mais de uma pergunta, não precisa esperar ter todas as respostas só com esta.

Comment: Ok, eu irei especificar no post exatamente quais recursos eu planejo colocar e espero que assim eu obtenha ajuda.